# calculate the time taken for change of activity in android

Tags: java, android, function, mobile, android-activity

i have calculated the current running activity in an android mobile and detected the name of the application using the code below..

```
for (ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo aTask : alltasks) {
              task=aTask.baseActivity.getPackageName();
              try{
              ai=pm.getApplicationInfo(task,0);}
              catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
                ai = null;
            }
final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");
```

This will return the name of any application that is run in the mobile device...But is there any function to detect the change in activity of the current running application using its name? i need to calculate the time taken to change from one activity to another for current running application.

Comment: Are you trying to get the intent load time while changing ActivityA to ActivityB ?

Comment: yes right..but i need to do that for any application that is currently running...without the need of the app's source code...like using a service

Comment: Have you looked at `AccessibilityService`? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService.html

Comment: @hoomi i will take a look..im not aware of that service yet..is there any specific syntax or function to detect the change in activity using AccessibilityService?

Comment: I have not tried it myself but from the event types I see `TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED` and `TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED`. You may be able to do something with them. Maybe check the activity on top before and after the event is thrown.

Comment: @hoomi ok..should i use it in a condition along with the default value of those events?